# cannot skip login using telemetry on ChromeOS stable channel 57.0.2987.146

Tags: google-chrome-os, telemetry

I am using this command to launch an app on my chromeOS running on stable channel 57.0.2987.146

sudo dbus-send --system --type=method_call \
        --dest=org.chromium.SessionManager /org/chromium/SessionManager org.chromium.SessionManagerInterface.EnableChromeTesting boolean:true array:string:"\
        --load-apps=/usr/local/edgeclient_ext,--enable-nacl,\
        --enable-net-benchmarking,--metrics-recording-only,--no-default-browser-check,\
        --no-first-run,--enable-gpu-benchmarking,--no-proxy-server,--disable-background-networking,\
        --enable-smooth-scrolling,--enable-threaded-compositing,--remote-debugging-port=55597,\
        --start-maximized,--oobe-skip-postlogin,--vmodule=*/chromeos/net/*=2\,*/chromeos/login/*=2,--disable-gaia-services"

I was able to skip the login on ChromeOS 56. Did something change since i can no longer skip the login? .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the issue was with the "--enable-gpu-benchmarking" flag.
This caused a core and, to an end user, made it look like the oobe-skip-postlogin flag was not working.

After removing the “--enable-gpu-benchmarking” flag, this is working as expected.